# Update data to related tables yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have table `USR` and `ORGANIZATION` :

USR table

```
|ID | ID_APP | NAMA_APP|
```

ORGANIZATION table

```
|ID | NAMA |
```

I tried to insert data to `USR` table (ID_APP and NAMA_APP) from `ORGANIZATION` by ID (relationship). This my code :

UsersController :

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if (Yii::$app->request->post()) {
            try {
                $state = true;
                $data = Yii::$app->request->post();
                $transaction = Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
                $model->ID_APP = $data['USR']['ID_APP'];
                $model->NAMA_APP = $data['USR']['NAMA_APP'];

                if (!$model->save()) {
                    $ErrorMessage = $model->getErrorMessage($model->getErrors());
                    throw new Exception($ErrorMessage);
                }
                $transaction->commit();
                $message = "Success update Application ";
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $state = false;
                $transaction->rollback();
                $message = $e->getMessage();
            }
            if ($state) {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('successApplication', $message);
                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->ID]);
            } else {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('errorApplication', $message);
                return $this->render('view', ['id' => $model->ID]);
            }

        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

My View :

```
<?php $org = \app\models\ORGANIZATION::find()->all(); ?>
                <?= $form->field($model, 'ID_APP')->dropDownList(
                    ArrayHelper::map($org,'ID', 'NAMA'))->label('ID APP') ?>
```

I'm still beginner on `php` and `yii2` framework How to get NAMA_APP (`USR` table) from NAMA (`ORGANIZATION`)?

Answer (score 0):

Based  on you view assumuning that you post the ID_APP and need  to retrive the NAMA_APP for a separated store in USR

```
  // make accessible your ORGANIZAZTION model with use eg: 
  // use common\models\ORGANIZATION;  or  
  use yourapp\models\ORGANIZATION;

  public function actionUpdate($id)
      {
          $model = $this->findModel($id);

          if (Yii::$app->request->post()) {
              try {
                  $state = true;
                  $data = Yii::$app->request->post();
                  $transaction = Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
                  $model->ID_APP = $data['USR']['ID_APP'];

                  // then  you can use eg: the  find method 
                  // related to ORGANIZAZTION active record   

                  $modelOrg =  ORGANIZATION::find()->where(['ID_APP']=> $data['USR']['ID_APP'])->one();
                  $model->NAMA_APP =  $modelOrg->NAMA_APP

                  ....
```